# Identifying similar elements in a dataset to detect spammers

Tags: sql, excel, database, join, similarity

I am trying to identify spammers in my dataset.

My dataset has listing id, user id, email id and phone number. Listing id is the unique key and a single person can have multiple listings.

I have used fuzzy lookup to find similarity index between phone numbers and also used fuzzy lookup to generate similarity index between email ids.

I am trying to join the three tables with each of the matches reflecting in the front of the first table.

I have tried using `VLOOKUP` and data models but have failed due to lack of a common row.

Input:

```
Listing ID   User ID        Email ID        Phone no.
1               A               A1              A2
2               A               A1              A2
3               A               A1              A2
4               A               A1              A2
5               A               A1              A2
6               A               A1              A2
7               B               B1              B2
8               B               B1              B2
9               B               B1              B2
10              C               C1              C2
11              C               C1              C2
```

Fuzzy LookUp Analysis for Phone Number

```
Primary_Profile  Primary_Phone  Match_Profile  Match_Phone Similarity_Index
A                   A2              B             B2        0.9
B                   B2              A             A2        0.9
B                   B2              C             C2        0.7
```

Fuzzy LookUp Analysis for Email id

```
Primary_Profile Primary_Email   Matching_Profile    Matching_Email  Similarity_Index
B                B1                 G                    G1          0.8
```

Desired Result

```
Listing ID  User ID Email ID    Phone no.   Profile Match   Sim Index   Sim Type
1           A           A1          A2          B           0.9         Phone
2           A           A1          A2          B           0.9         Phone
3           A           A1          A2          B           0.9         Phone
4           A           A1          A2          B           0.9         Phone
5           A           A1          A2          B           0.9         Phone
6           A           A1          A2          B           0.9         Phone
7           B           B1          B2          A           0.9         Phone
8           B           B1          B2          A           0.9         Phone
9           B           B1          B2          A           0.9         Phone
7           B           B1          B2          C           0.7         Phone
8           B           B1          B2          C           0.7         Phone
9           B           B1          B2          C           0.9         Phone
7           B           B1          B2          G           0.8         Email
8           B           B1          B2          G           0.8         Email
9           B           B1          B2          G           0.8         Email
```

Comment: Can you express the logic that leads to the desired result in words?

Comment: Is this a SQL question or an Excel question?  You've tagged both, formatted like a SQL question, and mentioned `VLOOKUP`, so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union all like this. Note I replaced your table names with #a, #b, and #c respectively and used generic columns.

```
 select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, b.col3, b.col5 , 'Phone' Sim_type from #A a
 join #b b on a.col2=b.col1
 union all
 select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, b.col3, b.col5, 'Email' from #A a
 join #c b on a.col2=b.col1
 order by   Sim_type desc, b.col5 desc, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3
```